# Quick syntax issue

Tags: php, string, variables, header

I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ')' in /storage/ssd2/202/1552202/public_html/randomreview.php on line 7

I don't really know what's wrong with it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id1552202_accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');
  $random = $db->prepare("SELECT path FROM Reviews ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
      $random->execute();
 while($result = $random->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
      $path = $result['path'];
      header('Location: https://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/'$path);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Also `exit` after the `header`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to concatenate

```
header('Location: https://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/'.$path);
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^----------

Answer (score 0):

> don't need ; ( semicolon) in `SELECT path FROM Reviews ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");`  after limit 1 . And check your concate in header .

```
<?php
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id1552202_accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');
  $random = $db->prepare("SELECT path FROM Reviews ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
      $random->execute();
 while($result = $random->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
      $path = $result['path'];
      header('Location: https://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/'.$path);
        }
?>
```

Comment: ("SELECT path FROM Reviews ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"); .... Check this.. and also your concate variable with string in 7 line... ( header ) Line.